# How to construct simple neural network which tells whether two embedding from different space belong to same class or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

In classical neural network we have (X,Y) where the goal of the neural network is to predict Y, given X. In my case I have embedding from two different space..lets call them M and N and binary label Y which tells whether these embedding belong to same class or not. Now the problem becomes ((M,N), Y) where value of Y is 1(same) or 0(different). How to construct a neural network to handle this type of data. One naive way can be to concatenate M and N and then go about predicting Y, but since M and N are coming from different embedding space, it is giving inferior performance.

```
input_Dim = M.shape(0) + N.shape(0)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_Dim,)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I was wondering if I can construct two different neural network, one takes input M and other takes input N and then output of these two neural network are combined to predict Y or not. Is that the way to handle such problem or is there any other way? Can it be done using keras or tensorflow. If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Keras functional API model:

```
input1 = Input(shape_of_embed_1)
input2 = Input(shape_of_embed_2)

#build net 1 from input 1
out1 = SomeLayer(...)(input1)
out1 = SomeOtherLayer(...)(out1)

#build net 2 from input 2
out2 = SomeLayer(...)(input2)
out2 = SomeOtherLayer(...)(out2)

#Concatenate
out = Concatenate()([out1,out2])

#Continue model
out = SomeLayer(...)(out)
out = SomeOtherLayer(...)(out)

#Finish
model = Model([input1, input2], out)

#Train
model.compile(optimizer=..., loss=...)
model.fit([embeddings1, embeddings2], y, ...)
```